# Config snappy support for spark in Windows

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, snappy

I am working on importing snappy compressed json file into spark rdd or dataset. However I meet this error:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy()Z

I have set the following configuration:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName("normal spark")
            .setMaster("local")
            .set("spark.io.compression.codec", "org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec")
            .set("spark.driver.extraLibraryPath","D:\\Downloads\\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\\jars")
            .set("spark.driver.extraClassPath","D:\\Downloads\\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\\jars")
            .set("spark.executor.extraLibraryPath","D:\\Downloads\\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\\jars")
            .set("spark.executor.extraClassPath","D:\\Downloads\\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\\jars")
            ;
```

Where D:\Downloads\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7 is my spark unpacked path, and I can find the snappy jar file snappy-0.2.jar and snappy-java-1.1.2.6.jar in

> D:\Downloads\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\

However nothing works and even the error message not change.

How can I fix it?